# Underpowered study

Tags: r, regression, bootstrap

I am currently doing data analysis for a study where I have 3 groups of very different sizes. First one is $n=22$, second $n=66$ and 3rd $n=167$. I have 2 dependent variables which are 2 different sleep scores. I have 7 independent variables. I am running multiple regressions for each group with all the IVs.

Two of the groups are obviously underpowered, esp the first one. Is my best option just to say that and then say that we ran linear regressions for each IV instead? Also, there are no between-group differences for the second IV. Is there any point running the regressions separately for each group?

And for my primary analyses I ran a regression `lm(sleepcore ~ condition)` where condition is the 3 groups (I dummy coded) and it shows up as sufficiently powered but considering the massive difference between all the groups, is this the case? Someone suggested bootstrapping

---

(to follow up my comment)

Thank you so much! So in the end I've gone with a hierarchical multiple regression including 1, 2, 3 and 5 of the IVs + their interactions with my groups which are dummy coded into 2 predictors (autistic and high trait) with low trait being baseline. The only thing is that since there's such a big difference in my groups, I want to additionally do a bootstrap regression (the model which was most significant in the anova I did for model comparison). So I did (in R):

```r
hr3 <- lm(sciscore ~ IV1 + IV2 + IV3 + 
    IV1 : autistic_v_lt + IV2:autistic_v_lt + IV3: autistic_v_lt + 
    IV1 : ht_v_lt + IV2:ht_v_lt+ IV3: ht_v_lt, data)

system.time(hr3.boot <- Boot(hr3, R=10000))
summary(hr3.boot)

## Output:
Number of bootstrap replications R = 10000 
                         original   bootBias  bootSE   bootMed
(Intercept)             17.229596  0.0183695 0.54525 17.242299
IV1               -1.778041 -0.0703439 0.84716 -1.799577
IV2                -1.281536  0.0483518 0.74418 -1.247199
IV3              -1.324919  0.0077572 0.68953 -1.305050
IV1:autistic_v_lt   1.979729 -0.2639083 2.32704  1.916440
IV2:autistic_v_lt  -5.098552  0.1406098 1.98166 -5.017870
IV3:autistic_v_lt  2.383142  0.0752194 1.85408  2.517646
IV1:ht_v_lt        -1.401699  0.0456044 1.51412 -1.355266
IV2:ht_v_lt         0.068447 -0.0050160 1.37996  0.044934
IV3:ht_v_lt        0.345885 -0.0585721 1.20377  0.301006
Bootstrap normal confidence intervals

print(confint(hr3.boot, level=.90, type="norm"))
hist(hr3.boot)
```

And ended up with my confidence intervals which are:

```r
(Intercept) 16.314372   18.1080808      
gsqvis_c    -3.101158   -0.3142363      
gsqtac_c    -2.553959   -0.1058176      
gsqgust_c   -2.466848   -0.1985051      
gsqvis_c:autistic_v_lt  -1.583997   6.0712713       
gsqtac_c:autistic_v_lt  -8.498705   -1.9796195      
gsqgust_c:autistic_v_lt -0.741774   5.3576191       
gsqvis_c:ht_v_lt    -3.937815   1.0432092       
gsqtac_c:ht_v_lt    -2.196364   2.3432910       
gsqgust_c:ht_v_lt   -1.575574   2.3844883
```

These are just the 3 IV names btw
The only thing now is I dont know how to interpret this. So my original values are all kind of in the middle of the CIs. Do I just use those to be more specific about where the observed effect value lies in the population or does that mean its more or not more significant? I just don't really know what to do with this output.

Comment: What kind of data are the sleep scores?  Are they continuous, categorical, something else?  Do you have a statistics consulting center in your university or access to a statistician in your research group?

Comment: @RCarnell they are both continuous. I'm working with my supervsior to work something out but she's not a statistician and I think all the options aren't great. I was going to do hierarchical regression/anova model comparison kind of arbitrarily based on the IVs that are significant based on previous research and the ones that i found were highly correlated to my DVs.

Answer (score 1):

Assumption:  the null hypothesis is that the mean group sleep scores are equal after accounting for the independent variables.

Let $Y_{ij}$ be the $j^{th}$ sleep score for the $i^{th}$ person.  And $Y_i$ is a vector of two sleep scores for the $i^{th}$ person.  Let $x_1,i$ and $x_2,i$ be dummy variables to encode group 1, 2, 3.

Multivariate regression accounts for the covariates and for the correlation between the dependent variables.

$$Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{1,i} + \beta_2x_{2,i} + \beta X_{Other\ IVs} + \epsilon$$

Other questions that need to be answered:

1. Does the regression fit meet the regression diagnostic measures?
2. Do any of the variables need transformed (log, sqrt, etc)?
3. If the regression does not meet the diagnostic measures, then bootstrapping may be one way to test the main hypothesis.

Example:

```r
n1 <- 22
n2 <- 66
n3 <- 167

set.seed(12344)
Y <- matrix(rnorm(2*(n1 + n2 + n3), 2), ncol = 2)

X <- data.frame(group = c(rep("A", n1), rep("B", n2), rep("C", n3)),
                iv1 = rnorm(n1+n2+n3, 2, 2),
                iv2 = rnorm(n1+n2+n3, 1, 2),
                iv3 = rnorm(n1+n2+n3, 1.5, 3))

mlm1 <- lm(Y ~ group + iv1 + iv2 + iv3, data = X)
summary(mlm1) # insufficient evidence to conclude that groupB or groupC is different from groupA for either response

plot(predict(mlm1)[,1], resid(mlm1)[,1], ylab = "residual", xlab = "Predicted Y1")
plot(predict(mlm1)[,2], resid(mlm1)[,2], ylab = "residual", xlab = "Predicted Y2")

qqnorm(resid(mlm1)[,1])
qqline(resid(mlm1)[,1], col = "red")

qqnorm(resid(mlm1)[,2])
qqline(resid(mlm1)[,2], col = "red")

fit1 <- manova(Y ~ group + iv1 + iv2 + iv3, data = X)
summary(fit1) # insufficient evidence to conclude that group is a significant predictor of either response
```